# How is the word '등' used in this sentence?

Tags: grammar, translation, idiom, dependent-noun

등's definition is: a bound noun used to indicate that there are other things of the same kind as the thing that was just mentioned.

우크라이나 수도 키우프 제2 도시 하리코프에 집중 포격을 가하는 등 공격의 고삐를 늦추지 않았습니다.

I can't understand the sense of 등 in this sentence.

There is a concentrated bombardment on Kiev and Kharkiv, and (?) they don't want to slacken the reins of the attack.

How is a bombardment of the same kind as alleviating the intensity of an attack?

Answer (score 2):

This is your mistranslation. You need to interpret the two clauses separately.

---

### 등

> a bound noun used to indicate that there are other things of the same kind as the thing that was just mentioned.

“**등**” is like “**and et cetera**; **and so on**,” in English, *implying* other more things of the same kind. “공격의 고삐를 늦추지 않았습니다.” is **not** what the “등” is *implying*.

When “**등**” is used with a clause (a verb), it works like a participle phrase (adverbial) in English: it translates to “***Verb*-ing … and so on,**”.

“우크라이나 수도 키우프 제2 도시 하리코프에 집중 포격을 가하는 등,” translates to “Bombarding on Kiev and Kharkiv and so on,”.

---

### “공격의 고삐를 늦추지 않았습니다.”

“**고삐를 늦추다**” (literally “to slacken/loosen the reins”) is an idiom that means “**to *lower* the intensity**,” by analogy with horse-riding. A horse stops running if you slacken the reins.

“고삐를 늦추지 않았습니다” is a negation of that: “***not*** to lower the intensity; to *increase* the intensity.”

And with “공격의” (“of the attack”), it means “they did ***not*** lower the intensity of the attack,” which is the opposite of “*alleviating*.”